# SSRS, In cascading parameter only the last ordered parameter greys out

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have two issues with SSRS.

1. I have cascading parameter. User selects first parameter (@place) and on that 
   basis last two parameters (@group and @cost) should grey out. Currently Only 
   the last parameter (@cost) greys out, not the second last (@group) getting 
   "select a value". If I swap the order then the @group greys out and @cost 
    does not
2. When I run the report in my local system, the cascading parameters only works for first time. When I change the @place parameter value then the rest parameters do not update..

Update: Mock Example below:
[image: This is my dataset which gives default values to A,B,C,D reports]

[image: This is the parameter group by]

[image: This is the parameter calculation]

[image: This is the issue below. When C is selected I want both parameters to be greyed out. In first pictue, I have mentioned Null for both when C is selected]

This is the issue in pic above. When C is selected I want both parameters to be greyed out. In first picture, I have mentioned Null for both when C is selected

Comment: @StevenWhite - Could you please help me this. I have gone through your post on a question like this but still only parameter (last one) greys out.

Comment: I think the issue you're having is related to having the values set as _default_ values.  You might need to set these as _available_ values.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a dummy project with other fields in order to solve this scenario. My fields are LAST_DATE_EDITED, ID and FEE_AMOUNT in which ID and FEE_AMOUNT are dependent of LAST_DATE_EDITED field.

In order to do this, I created 3 datasets for each parameter. For LAST_DATE_EDITED I put only a SELECT LAST_DATE_EDITED from test table. For ID and FEE_AMOUNT I did as below:

[image]

In this way, I achieved the following output:

[image]

[image]

I hope that I understood correctly and this will help you.

Comment: Hello Ana Thanks for your reply. I have added the screenshots in my question. Please check. Thank you.